# ASP.NET update div background color from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an empty ASP.NET page where all I have is a button and some Image control, to show a colored area to the user. As the user click the Start button, I would like to display colors successively into that Image control. It works for the FIRST iteration but that's it. My intuitive logic made me use a loop to wait 10 seconds between each new color but the control is never refreshed. If possible, I'd like to do this without resorting to an AJAX Update Panel (although I'm not sure how I'd do this?). Is this a "natural" candidate for stepping into JavaScript? To change the div background color dynamically?

Comment: An Update Panel should be able to do this as well. A code behind method called from your button should be able to set the div color to whatever you like, every time you press it. Let's see the code you have so far.

Comment: The UpdatePanel solution will not work because there should be no user intervention. I since settled on using a JavaScript solution which not completely working but it's heading in the right direction... I will post it now.